# mysql - select from column with multiply values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
$r=mysql_query(
    "SELECT * 
    FROM advertisements 
    WHERE 
        $filter exposure!='0' AND `status`='2' AND 
        (clicks_left_micro>0 OR clicks_left_mini>0 
        OR clicks_left_standard>0 OR clicks_left_extended>0 
        OR fixed='1') 
    ORDER BY 
        exposure DESC, fixed DESC"
```

);

In my `advertisements` table I have a column called `geoFilter`. That column can either be empty or it can contain values (country codes) like:

```
DK, US, CA, EN,
```

I get the users country code like this (stored in DB):

```
$userdata['country_code'];
```

My question is, how can I select from the `advertisements` table where users country code is present?

Comment: AND geoFilter IS NOT NULL

Comment: I don't need to get the results where geoFilter is not null, I need to get them where the users country code is there.

Comment: What's the difference between not NULL and value that "is there"?

Comment: if geoFilter has values "DK,US,CA" ex. then users ONLY from these countries should see it. If it's null, everyone, no matter country, should see it.

Comment: Though you can solve this problem by simply adding a `WHERE country_code LIKE(...)` element to your filter, you may want to consider normalizing the data in this column if you find yourself needing to do more complex queries on this column.

Comment: @MikeBrant could you make an example with the LIKE(..)?

Comment: @oliverbj See the example in answer by MacDefender below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to start your WHERE clause with: WHERE country_code LIKE „%US%“ AND (…) to get only results where US is contained in the country_code column.